# UICollectionView wrong indexPath.section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview which has (`items.count / 2`) number of sections and each sections has two items in it. I had to use section in order to be able to set footer for each row.
the problem is that in `cellForItemAt indexPath` method the value of `indexPath.section` is not returned in the correct order.
here is my code for `cellForItemAt indexPath` :

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LibraryCell",for: indexPath) as! LibraryCell
    cell.cover.image = nil
    var position = 0
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        position = indexPath.section * 2
    }else {
        position = (indexPath.section * 2) + 1
    }

    print("section: " + String(indexPath.section) + "   row: " + String(indexPath.row) + "   item: " + String(indexPath.item))
    let book = items[position] as! MyBooksTable
    if let url = URL(string: String(book.coverUrl ?? "")){

        cell.cover.kf.setImage(with: url, placeholder: UIImage(named: "cover_placeholder"), options: [.transition(.fade(0.2))], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
    }

    return cell
}
```

and the result of the print method uppon scrolling down is:

`section: 5   row: 0   item: 0
section: 5   row: 1   item: 1
section: 6   row: 0   item: 0
section: 6   row: 1   item: 1
section: 7   row: 0   item: 0
section: 7   row: 1   item: 1
section: 2   row: 0   item: 0
section: 2   row: 1   item: 1
section: 7   row: 0   item: 0
section: 7   row: 1   item: 1
section: 8   row: 0   item: 0
section: 8   row: 1   item: 1
section: 9   row: 0   item: 0
section: 9   row: 1   item: 1
section: 4   row: 0   item: 0
section: 4   row: 1   item: 1
section: 9   row: 0   item: 0
section: 9   row: 1   item: 1
section: 10   row: 0   item: 0
section: 10   row: 1   item: 1
section: 11   row: 0   item: 0
section: 11   row: 1   item: 1
section: 12   row: 0   item: 0
section: 12   row: 1   item: 1
section: 7   row: 0   item: 0
section: 7   row: 1   item: 1
section: 12   row: 0   item: 0
section: 12   row: 1   item: 1
section: 13   row: 0   item: 0
section: 13   row: 1   item: 1
section: 14   row: 0   item: 0
section: 14   row: 1   item: 1
section: 15   row: 0   item: 0
section: 15   row: 1   item: 1
section: 16   row: 0   item: 0
section: 16   row: 1   item: 1
section: 17   row: 0   item: 0
section: 17   row: 1   item: 1
section: 18   row: 0   item: 0
section: 18   row: 1   item: 1
section: 19   row: 0   item: 0
section: 19   row: 1   item: 1
section: 20   row: 0   item: 0
section: 20   row: 1   item: 1
section: 21   row: 0   item: 0
section: 21   row: 1   item: 1
section: 16   row: 0   item: 0
section: 16   row: 1   item: 1
section: 21   row: 0   item: 0
section: 21   row: 1   item: 1
section: 22   row: 0   item: 0
section: 22   row: 1   item: 1
section: 23   row: 0   item: 0
section: 23   row: 1   item: 1
section: 24   row: 0   item: 0
section: 24   row: 1   item: 1`

as you can see there is 7 after 12 .... 16 after 21 and so on...
which results in wrong data rendering and I can not figure out the reason why.

Comment: "method the value of indexPath.section is not returned in the correct order" Why is that a problem? I don't see why it's a problem in your code.

Comment: @Larme because the returned data for the cell is wrong. data is not read correctly from the array

Comment: If you do `let book = items[position] as! MyBooksTable`, it shouldn't matter, the order of which one is called isn't important.

Comment: The order that `cellForItemAt` is irrelevant. But update your question with your `numberOfSection` and `numberOfItemsInSection` methods.